# Insert JSON into MySQL.

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have .json file [categories.json]

like this

```
{
    "apple": [
        "fruit",
        "15"
    ],
    "cat": [
        "animal",
        "400"
    ],
    "pumpkin": [
        "vegetables",
        "20"
    ],
    "orange": [
        "fruit",
        "30"
    ]
}
```

i want to insert json object into mysql using loop php like this

```
|___id__|___ product__|_____type_____|__price__|
|   1   |     apple   |    fruit     |    15   |
|   2   |     cat     |    animal    |    400  |
|   3   |   pumpkin   |  vegetables  |    20   |
|   4   |    orange   |    fruit     |    30   |
```

how can i do thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
 $file = 'www.mysite.com/categories.json';
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

foreach($data as $product => $row){
$sql = "INSERT INTO product ";
  $sql .= "SET product='".mysql_real_escape_string($product)."',type='".mysql_real_escape_string($row[0])."',price=".mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
mysql_query($sql);
} // hoping your id field in db is auto_increment
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @quentin yes. I just tried to give a simple answer so that he understand  better .. May be he will implement with all those check in PDO or mysqli

Comment: in this line `$file = 'var/www/somefile.json';` 

my file location is www.mysite.com/categories.json , then i write `$file = 'var/www/categories.json';` but not work (not insert) how can i do ?

Comment: use www.mysite.com/categories.json as your path to file_get_content that should work

Comment: are you using mysqli or mysql ?

Answer (score 1):

just use json_decode to convert your Json file into a an array and then loop and insert as you'd do that with an array